# Error running Jboss EAP 6.3 from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss6.x

I'm getting this error only when I start Jboss from eclipse, when I run out of eclipse, it runs correctly.

I'm using JBoss EAP 6.3.

```
    ERROR [fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."example.ear"."example-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."example.ear"."example-ejb.jar".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "example-ejb.jar" of deployment "example.ear"
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:127)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS018757: Error getting reflective information for class com.jboss.examples.ejb.ExampleSingleton with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.example.ear.example-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:72)
  at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:107)
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:77)
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:120)
  ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/jboss/examples/Example;
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
  at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57)
  at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:68)
  ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jboss.examples.Example from [Module "deployment.example.ear.example-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
  at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373)
  at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118)
  ... 15 more
```

Does anyone know what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove any deployed projects in server from server tab. try to start the server. export war file from eclipse and try to deploy it from management console.

or you can try rebuild your project.

This may because your build doesn't contain required *.class files.

Comment: I solved my problem rebuilding the project like you suggested, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This was happening because of the scope that I was using for my dependency in Maven build.
I was using provided, thus, I changed for the default scope "compile"

There are 6 scopes available:

compile
This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

provided
This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

runtime
This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

test
This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases.

system
This scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository.

import (only available in Maven 2.0.9 or later)
This scope is only used on a dependency of type pom in the 'dependencyManagement' section. It indicates that the specified POM should be replaced with the dependencies in that POM's 'dependencyManagement' section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

I was using:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>entity</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Then I changed to:

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>br.com.web</groupId>
                <artifactId>entity</artifactId>
            </dependency>
```